# Android 8.0 adb device keeps unauthorized after authorisation

Tags: android, adb, unauthorized

Edit: I did some deeper investigation, but still no clue what causes the problem.

- When I plugin my usb cable the phone asks: "Allow access to phone data"
- I'm sure I have allowed the access but keep getting **unauthorized**

> ```
> adb usb
> error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog...
>
> adb devices
> ce051605a5378d1b03      unauthorized
>
> adb connect 192.168.1.6
> unable to connect to 192.168.1.6:5555
> ```

Connecting over wifi also doesn't work, that is the correct ip as I setted it fixed.

What can be the cause and how can I fix it?
Running on Samsung Android 8.0 and connected to PC Win7 x64.

Comment: download adb from this http://adbshell.com/downloads

Comment: @Biswapriyo that is the one that I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you're using Windows follow these steps, after i tried every solution and almost gave up i found the following and it worked.**

- First things first:
- **Phone**: Check if you have a file called **adb_keys** located at: */data/misc/adb/adb_keys*. If you have it, i would recommend you to backup the file. (I didn't have it.)
- **Windows**: You'll need to have a file called **adbkey.pub** located at *C:/users/UserAccount/.android/*
- Boot into **recovery mode.**
- Plug your phone into PC.
- Open **cmd** and run `adb devices`. It would show "*recovery*" instead "*unauthorized*".
- Create a new file called **adb_keys** file on your PC:

  ```
  type NUL > adb_keys
  ```
- Now you need to copy the contents from the **adbkey.pub** to **adb_keys**, the new file you just created: 
  **adbkey.pub** is located at *C:/users/UserAccount/.android/*
  (Needless to say you need to replace "UserAccount" when running the command)

  ```
  type c:\users\UserAccount\.android\adbkey.pub > adb_keys
  ```
- Upload the **adb_keys** file to your phone:

  ```
  adb push adb_keys /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
  ```
- Reboot and run adb devices. It should be working now.

*Thank mnoguti [from this post on XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=73589131&postcount=5) for this answer.*

***[If you have Linux that's the same solution with Unix commands.](http://www.neuraldump.com/2017/05/how-to-fix-adb-unauthorized-error/)***

Comment: amazing, this really did the trick! just like in your case the adb_keys was not available on my device. now it works perfect!